# Keras: Access confidence inside custom loss function

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I have my own custom loss function into which I pass the input in order to do some calculations. I would like to access the confidence for each prediction and use that in my loss function.
The loss function takes `y_true, y_pred`, and by wrapping it in an other function I can pass it extra data.

Is there any way to have access to the confidence of each prediction during training?

Comment: y_pred is literally the confidence (for a softmax outputs).

Comment: Thanks. I had not realised that this is actually it.